# Why does limit not limit the amount of data queried in bigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery that is about 50TB which is about 400,000,000,000 rows, I am trying to create a sample of that table to prevent incurring huge cost on processing the entire table

```
  CREATE TABLE `my_sample_table`
  (
    myCol1 INT64 NOT NULL,
    myCol2 INT64 NOT NULL,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    myCount INT64,
    myVal1 INT64,
    myVal2 INT64,
    mypartition TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  )
  PARTITION BY DATE(mypartition)
  OPTIONS(
    labels=[("myLabel", "false")]
  );



  INSERT INTO `my_sample_table`
  (
    myCol1,
    myCol2,
    timestamp,
    myCount,
    myVal1,
    myVal2,
    mypartition)
  SELECT
    myCol1,
    myCol2,
    timestamp,
    myCount,
    myVal1,
    myVal2,
    mypartition,
  FROM `my_table`
  LIMIT 400000
```

why is the process of creating the table causing the entire table to be scanned?

> This query will process 51.5 TiB when run.

I expected 1/100,000 th of data to be used instead?

Comment: `LIMIT` is applied after result is calculated and just set how many rows from that result to return. So, `LIMIT 1` and `LIMIT 400000` will process same amount of data as if no `LIMIT` applied at all. But obviously amount of data returned will be different

Comment: Consider using the `TABLESAMPLE` method outlined here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-sampling